# AngularJs iOS App - advice on popup screen with blurred background

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, single-page-application

I am making a non native iOS app in html/javascript/Css3. In response to a particular event I want a menu to popup where the user is asked a question and they can answer it before returning to the normal screen. I want the normal screen to be inactive and blurred while the popup screen is in action.

Does anyone have any advice into anything I can look at or any techniques to achieve the popup screen and inactivity and blurring of the background?
I'm very new to this so would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you setup your backgbround to be a HTML5 canvas you can use CSS Filters, given the framework supports them:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/CSS-Filter-Effects-Landing-in-WebKit

```
img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Also have a look at the libraries mentioned here:
http://creativejs.com/2011/12/day-5-blur-that-canvas/

They also rely on having a HTML5 canvas but don't rely on CSS Filters.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look!